# What is the role of 'server' in an embedded server dbms? - Confusion over the many 'server'-related terms that pop up when looking for a suited rdbms

Tags: sql-server, database, rdbms, serverless

I'll give you a bit of background because I don't think my question is clear without it. Aside from that, I don't know much about servers but I think it'll become clear what I'm actually asking because of the background information.

I was/am building a small C++ program to be used by just me (a homework manager, which needed to keep track of tasks, so it relied on tasks and subtasks and needed multiple tables, etc.), so I figured I needed a database. I quickly stumbled upon SQLite, which was perfect for my case in many ways: -it's free, -it only uses .db files which can be interpreted by any software, -it can be embedded, -it's simple (in terms of documentation and libraries), *and most importantly*: [-it is what SQLite.org describes as 'serverless'](https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html).

However, I found SQLite's dynamic type system extremely annoying ('why' is besides the point; I might make seperate posts asking questions about this) and I decided to look for a rdbms that has all the pros I mentioned above but also has static typing.

While going down this rabbit-hole of looking for a rdbms to fit my needs, I came across many terms which were all related to how the rdbms is implemented regarding the term 'server' and the like. All the terms are very vagues and one word does not mean the same every instance.

I noticed all of these keywords and contrasts popping up during my search:

- Stand-alone vs server/client
- Embedded vs... 'not embedded', I guess(?)
- Classic serverless vs neo-serverless
- Serverless... but in reality cloud-based (I thought clouds were servers(?))
- Server vs service
- Service vs application
- User vs client

I'm as far as to know that a server is a proces that is executing on the background, not to be used by the user directly. But other than that, all these server-related terms are throwing me off.

I want a rdbms that has this 'serverless'ness SQLite.org speaks of. I saw many professional free SQL RDBMS providers which spoke of the ability to have 'embedded servers', which does contain the word 'embedded' but it also contains 'server'. *So my question is:* when a providers speaks of these 'embedded servers', what does it really mean?

*Does it mean that there is one application, and when it runs it opens another application which functions as a server? And when it does so, is that server a service or just another normal application-like process? Or, does it work exactly the same like the serverlessness SQLite mentions, that being: the libraries inside of the compiled project already handle everything to work with only .db files? Does it need any files other than the database and the executable? Does the communication between the application and database file directly come from the code or is another proces used?*

(PS: as a side-question: could you help me clear up what all the terms in the list above precisely mean?)

I realise my question might be all over the place, but so is the vocabulary I've come across in this journey. I hope you can understand where my confusion is coming from and can help me clear these points up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By "serverless" SQLLite just means that it's a library, and doesn't run in a seperate process.  In this it's like Access/Jet and other older DMBS programs that read and write files directly.  The more common term for this is "[embedded database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database)".

The more common meaning of "serverless" these days is a cloud-based capability that doesn't require you to install or manage a "server" or VM.  As in "We use [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) for serverless compute".

The *other* DMBS systems are typically called "Client-Server DBMS", where the DMBS runs in a seperate process and the client program communicates with it over a network or some RPC mechanism.  Client-Server RDBMS systems can be "bundled" or "embedded" with an application, and may not be running on a seperate computer, but would still be running in a seperate process.

Comment: (1/2) "By "serverless" SQLLite just means that it's a library, and doesn't run in a seperate process" I still don't really know how that works / what that means though. For example, take a look at how [Firebird describes their embedded version](https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/ufb-cs-embedded.html) (first seven lines); they mention stuff like 'an embedded server locking a database after a succesful _connection_', and 'multiple apps _connecting_ at the same time to the same _(embedded) server_', and 'The Windows Embedded Server is a Superserver engine plus client rolled into one'.

Comment: (2/2) I don't quite see how that's similar to what SQLite does. This all sounds like server-like behaviour. It's obviously different, but what sets it apart?

Comment: Looks like Firebird supports both modes, client/server and embedded.